# AJAX not firing in JSF 2.0

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have a problem that my AJAX requests are not firing in JSF, for unknown reasons.

**admin.xhtml Snippet:**

```
<h:form id="adminPanel">
...
<f:subview id="editCustomer#{customer.id}">
    <p class="#{adminService.getEditCustomerClass(customer.id)}">
        <h:inputText id="email#{customer.id}" value="#{adminService.customerEmail}"/><br/>
        <h:inputText id="firstName#{customer.id}" value="#{adminService.customerFirstName}"/>
        <h:inputText id="lastName#{customer.id}" value="#{adminService.customerLastName}"/><br/>
        <h:commandButton id="saveEdit#{customer.id}" type="button" value="Save">
            <f:ajax render="@form" event="click" listener="#{adminService.saveCustomer()}"/>
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:commandButton id="cancelEdit#{customer.id}" type="button" value="Cancel">
            <f:ajax render="@form" event="click" listener="#{adminService.cancelEdit()}"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </p>
</f:subview>
...
</h:form>
```

**AdminService.java Snippet:**

```
@Named
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class AdminService {

    public String getEditCustomerClass(int id) {
        return id != customerId ? "hidden" : "";
    }

    public void saveCustomer() {
        cancelEdit();
    }

    public void cancelEdit() {
        movieId = -1;
        customerId = -1;
        orderId = -1;
        actorId = -1;
        employeeId = -1; //if none of the id's match, p should return 'hidden' class and not be seen.
    }

}
```

Originally I had problems because instead of hiding and showing with CSS, I was using the "rendered=" attribute. However, I heard that partial rendering of views can break AJAX, so I phased it out, hoping that not partially rendering the view (only hiding and showing it) would fix the problem.

However this ajax is still not calling the method I specified in the listener attribute (the entire page is a lot bigger and uses a lot more AJAX, though the rest of it works until these buttons are pressed, then other ajax buttons stop responding.)

If I change the button type to submit, it will actually perform the listener method if I press the button twice, but then the other ajax links don't call their respective listener methods.

How can I get this to work?

**Update:**

Here is the information from POST request that JSF fires on click:

**Request Headers:**

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2186
Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=7342e0de92edc023eecbf706dae3
Faces-Request:partial/ajax
Host:www.minimalcomputers.com:8181
Origin:https://www.minimalcomputers.com:8181
Referer:https://www.minimalcomputers.com:8181/MovieProject/Admin/admin.xhtml
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
```

**Form Data:**

```
adminPanel:adminPanel
adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:0:editCustomer1:email1:phroph@yahoo.com
adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:0:editCustomer1:firstName1:
adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:0:editCustomer1:lastName1:
adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:1:editCustomer1:email1:phroph@yahoo.com
adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:1:editCustomer1:firstName1:
adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:1:editCustomer1:lastName1:
adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:2:editCustomer1:email1:phroph@yahoo.com
adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:2:editCustomer1:firstName1:
adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:2:editCustomer1:lastName1:
adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:3:editCustomer1:email1:phroph@yahoo.com
adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:3:editCustomer1:firstName1:
adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:3:editCustomer1:lastName1:
adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:4:editCustomer1:email1:phroph@yahoo.com
adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:4:editCustomer1:firstName1:
adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:4:editCustomer1:lastName1:
javax.faces.ViewState:1088200739038195170:4402027985833798256
javax.faces.source:adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:0:editCustomer1:cancelEdit1
javax.faces.partial.event:click
javax.faces.partial.execute:adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:0:editCustomer1:cancelEdit1             adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:0:editCustomer1:cancelEdit1
javax.faces.partial.render:adminPanel
javax.faces.behavior.event:click
javax.faces.partial.ajax:true
```

**Response Header**

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 02 May 2013 21:45:05 GMT
Server:GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 Java/Sun Microsystems Inc./1.6)
X-Powered-By:JSF/2.0
```

**Update 2:**

When I switch to commandButtons of type "submit" without AJAX, it works as expected (except some of the buttons requires two clicks to activate). So the problem is localized to the f:ajax tags.

**Update 3:**

The entire base of code for admin.xhtml. IT's a bit unclean because it's in the process of being debugged and trying things to make it work.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="header.css" library="css"/>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
        <title>VideoPile - Administration</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div id="body">
            <ui:insert name="header" >
                <ui:include src="/templates/header.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
            <div id="content">
                Admin.
                <h:form id="adminPanel">
                    <!--<h:commandButton id="admin" value="Administrative Actions" rendered="{adminService.hasAdminPrivileges()}">
                        <f:ajax render="@form" event="click" listener="{adminService.toggleAdminPane()}"/>
                    </h:commandButton>-->
                    <h:commandButton id="manager" type="button" value="Manager Actions" rendered="#{adminService.hasManagerPrivileges()}">
                        <f:ajax render="@form" event="click" listener="#{adminService.toggleManagerPane()}"/>
                    </h:commandButton>
                    <h:commandButton id="representative" type="button" value="Representative Actions" rendered="#{adminService.hasRepresentativePrivileges()}">
                        <f:ajax render="@form" event="click" listener="#{adminService.toggleRepresentativePane()}" />
                    </h:commandButton>
                    <br/>
                    <!--<f:subview id="administrativeActionPane" rendered="{userService.showAdminPane}">
                        Admin Pane
                    </f:subview>-->
                    <f:subview id="managerialActionPane">
                        <div class="#{adminService.getShowManagerClass()}">
                        Manager Pane:
                        <h:commandLink id="editmovies" value="Movies">
                            <f:ajax render="@form" event="click" listener="#{adminService.toggleMoviePane()}"/>
                        </h:commandLink>
                        <h:commandLink id="employes" value="Employees">
                            <f:ajax render="@form" event="click" listener="#{adminService.toggleEmployeePane()}"/>
                        </h:commandLink>
                        <h:commandLink id="sales" target="_blank" value="View Sales Report" action="/Admin/salesreport"/>
                        <h:commandLink id="employees" target="_blank" value="View Most Active Employees" action="/Admin/activeemployees"/>
                        <h:commandLink id="customers" target="_blank" value="View Most Active Customers" action="/Admin/activecustomers"/>
                        <h:commandLink id="movies" target="_blank" value="View Most Active Movies" action="/Admin/activemovies"/>
                        <br/>
                        <f:subview id="moviesEditPane">
                            <span class="#{adminService.getShowMovieClass()}">
                                Movies.
                                <ui:repeat value="#{adminService.currentMoviePage}" var="movie">
                                    #{movie.name}
                                    <h:commandLink id="edit" value="Edit">
                                        <f:ajax render="@form" event="click" listener="#{adminService.editMovie(movie.id)}"/>
                                    </h:commandLink> 
                                    <h:outputText rendered="#{adminService.movieId eq movie.id}" value="edit"/>
                                    <br/>
                                </ui:repeat>
                            </span>
                        </f:subview>
                        <f:subview id="employeesEditPane">
                            <span class="#{adminService.getShowEmployeeClass()}">
                                Employees.
                                <ui:repeat value="#{adminService.currentEmployeePage}" var="employee">
                                    #{employee.firstName} #{employee.lastName}
                                    <h:commandLink id="edit" value="Edit">
                                        <f:ajax render="@form" event="click" listener="#{adminService.editEmployee(employee.id)}"/>
                                    </h:commandLink> 
                                    <h:outputText rendered="#{adminService.employeeId eq employee.id}" value="edit"/>
                                    <br/>
                                </ui:repeat>
                            </span>
                        </f:subview>
                        </div>
                    </f:subview>
                    <f:subview id="representativeActionPane">
                        <div class="#{adminService.getShowRepresentativeClass()}">
                            Customer Representative Pane:
                            <h:commandLink id="recordOrder" value="Record Order">
                                <f:ajax render="@form" event="click" listener="#{adminService.toggleOrderPane()}"/>
                            </h:commandLink>
                            <h:commandLink id="customers" value="Customers">
                                <f:ajax render="@form" event="click" listener="#{adminService.toggleCustomerPane()}"/>
                            </h:commandLink>
                            <h:commandLink id="mailingList" target="_blank" value="View Mailing List" action="/Admin/mailinglist"/>
                            <f:subview id="orderPane">
                                <span class="#{adminService.getShowOrderClass()}">
                                    Create new order.
                                </span>
                            </f:subview>
                            <f:subview id="customerPane">
                                <span class="#{adminService.getShowCustomerClass()}">
                                    Customers.
                                    <ui:repeat id="customersList" value="#{adminService.currentCustomerPage}" var="customer">
                                        <f:subview id="editCustomer#{customer.id}">
                                            <p class="#{adminService.getEditCustomerClass(customer.id)}">
                                                <h:inputText id="email#{customer.id}" value="#{adminService.customerEmail}"/><br/>
                                                <h:inputText id="firstName#{customer.id}" value="#{adminService.customerFirstName}"/>
                                                <h:inputText id="lastName#{customer.id}" value="#{adminService.customerLastName}"/><br/>
                                                <h:commandButton id="saveEdit#{customer.id}" type="submit" value="Save" actionListener="#{adminService.saveCustomer()}">
                                                    <f:ajax render="@form" event="click" execute="@form"/>
                                                </h:commandButton>
                                                <h:commandButton id="cancelEdit#{customer.id}" type="submit" value="Cancel" actionListener="#{adminService.cancelEdit()}">
                                                    <f:ajax render="@form" event="click" execute="@form" />
                                                </h:commandButton>
                                            </p>
                                        </f:subview>
                                        <f:subview id="viewCustomer#{customer.id}">
                                            <p class="#{adminService.getViewCustomerClass(customer.id)}">
                                                #{customer.email}<br/>
                                                #{customer.firstName} #{customer.lastName}<br/>
                                                <h:commandLink id="suggestion" target="_blank" value="View Suggestions" action="/Admin/customersuggestions">
                                                    <f:param name="user" value="#{customer.id}"/>
                                                </h:commandLink>
                                                <h:commandButton id="edit" type="submit" value="Edit" action="#{adminService.editCustomer(customer)}">
                                                    <f:ajax render="@form" event="click" execute="@form" />
                                                </h:commandButton>
                                            </p>
                                        </f:subview>
                                        <br/>
                                    </ui:repeat>
                                </span>
                            </f:subview>
                        </div>
                    </f:subview>
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: shouldnt there be a <h:form> ?

Comment: @AkselWillgert There is an h:form on a higher-level. I didn't include that, my mistake.

Comment: Please elaborate "don't work" in developer's perspective instead of enduser's perspective. To start, look in the browser's JS console and HTTP traffic monitor.

Comment: @BalusC Sorry about that, I will clarify the terminology in the question. I added breakpoints to cancelEdit() and saveCustomer() and when I debugged the application on my server, when I pressed the buttons in question, my methods were never called, and the application didn't reflect the changes that I expected (the edit subview should've been hidden)

Comment: Is the JS code from `jsf.js` executed? Is the XML HTTP request created? Is it been sent? Does it hold the proper request parameters? Etc. As said, start at JS console and HTTP traffic monitor. Maybe there are JS errors. Maybe you can track it with JS debugger. Maybe you can see the HTTP request or not. Maybe you can verify the HTTP request. Etc.

Comment: @BalusC When I click the button, jsf.js initiates a POST request which  returns a status code 200. The content appears correct, but there is some aliasing of form data, probably because this snippet of code is within a ui:repeat. If you want, I can post the data from the POST request.

Comment: Is the `javax.faces.ViewState` request parameter present or absent during those requests which failed to invoke the action? If absent, then this problem is explainable (and thus this question is answerable).

Comment: @BalusC The POST request has the following javax parameters:
javax.faces.ViewState:1906032561572019845:-3202529067164453321
javax.faces.source:adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:0:editCustomer1:cancelEdit1
javax.faces.partial.event:click
javax.faces.partial.execute:adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:0:editCustomer1:cancelEdit1 adminPanel:representativeActionPane:customerPane:customersList:0:editCustomer1:cancelEdit1
javax.faces.partial.render:adminPanel
javax.faces.behavior.event:click
javax.faces.partial.ajax:true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, and the cause of it is really quite strange, but it makes sense.

In my ID's, I was using EL to define unique ID's for UIComponents (even though this was not necessary). When I remove the EL from the ID's, the ajax works!

I'm presuming (though I'm sure BalusC would give a more thorough answer), was that because the id's aren't static, even though the ID in concept would be the same, it was affecting the way JSF finds UIComponents.

Now I feel dumb, because the problem would've been completely avoidable if I didn't add any superfluous elements.

For example, the code in my original post should be as follows:

```
<h:form id="adminPanel">
...
<f:subview id="editCustomer">
    <p class="#{adminService.getEditCustomerClass(customer.id)}">
        <h:inputText id="email" value="#{adminService.customerEmail}"/><br/>
        <h:inputText id="firstName" value="#{adminService.customerFirstName}"/>
        <h:inputText id="lastName" value="#{adminService.customerLastName}"/><br/>
        <h:commandButton id="saveEdit" type="button" value="Save">
            <f:ajax render="@form" event="click" listener="#{adminService.saveCustomer()}"/>
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:commandButton id="cancelEdit" type="button" value="Cancel">
            <f:ajax render="@form" event="click" listener="#{adminService.cancelEdit()}"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </p>
</f:subview>
...
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason for submitting the form by the Javascript Event onclick?
I suggest you to call the action like this:

```
<h:commandButton id="saveEdit#{customer.id}" value="Submit" actionListener="#{adminService.saveCustomer()}">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Changing my code to use "execute=" and "actionListener=" instead does not work either. This might be a bug with JSF or simply my code is too convoluted.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this behaviour. Your code works for me, so There must be something wrong with the rest of your code. Try to find the problem by partly adding more code to your fragment. Maybe you have somewhere else a h:form open.

Comment: It's a small fragment of a larger page. I probably could've abstracted the views better and I'm slightly embarrassed of the code, but I will post it.

Comment: Ok i'll try tomorrow. I suggest you to clean up your code and use more local forms. Call actions as i mentioned above. Especially in your <ui:repeat> tag, there will be some problems if you wanna validate something, as you process the whole form.

Comment: See my answer. I figured out the issue.